# AADSTS76020: Azure AD SSO with Signin certificate cannot authenticate graph client

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I have an Azure Enterprise app that defines a SAML SSO with verification certificate. That same app has Api permission Graph User.Read.All and Group.Read.All.

SSO works fine, I am able to log my users in. But when I try to retrieve their group names via the graph api, my graph client cannot log in.
I get **AADSTS76020: Application configured to use only protocols with signed requests** error. From what I understand, I should sign my graph authentication requests but I don't think the authentication protocol allows that.

When I disable the certificate verification, my graph client can get its access token and I manage to get the group names.

Should I declare two apps (one for SSO, the other for Graph) or should I be able to do this?
Am I missing a configuration somewhere?

*Note: My Graph client authenticate using ClientId, ClientSecret and TenantId. I also tried with ClientId, Certificate and TenantId*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce in my environment and got the results as below:***

> **Note** that: To achieve your scenario, create two applications one for SSO, the other for Graph.

I created an **Azure AD Application and granted API permissions** as below:

[image]

I generated **access token** using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

[image]

By using the above generated access token, **I am able to get the user groups** successfully as below:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID/memberOf
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[List a user's direct memberships - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I understand correctly your Note "To achieve your scenario, create two applications one for SSO, the other for Graph.", it is not possible to achieve my scenario with a single Enterprise app? Is it a common good practice to have multiple Azure app (one by scope) for a single external app?

Comment: I ended up creating two apps to solve that incompatibility. One for SAML and the other for Graph authentication and authorization.